# Atlassian Forge: Where do I find type definitions for a trigger function

Tags: typescript, triggers, atlassian-forge, jira-forge

When I create a new app as a product trigger, then I get a index.jsx that looks like:

```
export async function run(event, context) {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

I can rename the index.jsx to tsx that the file is treated as Typescript file, but where do I find the definitions for `èvent` and `context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Atlassian staff I got following answer:

> we don’t have TS definitions for the event and context in code, but
> you can find some more detail about the payload for different product
> events at
> https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/events-reference/jira
>
> You could also try console.log the event and context functions and use
> the forge logs command to see what information there is.

You find it here: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/where-do-i-find-type-definitions-for-a-forge-trigger-function/51199/2